# gcloud deploy error "Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1", though my version is 2.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying deploy a GAE project for the first time, after successfully publishing one of the test apps, and i'm getting an error regarding a wrong ruby version. I'm not sure if it's one of the other gems, but i'm not familiar with ROR or GCS, and i'm not sure what else to do.
Thanks.

Here are some of my system settings:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin14]


$ rvm list
rvm rubies

 * ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]

$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.2
```

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.2'
ruby "2.4.1"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
#gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.0"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end



gem "rack"
gem "puma"
```

Comment: What's the ruby version in your `gemfile.lock` file? Does `bundle install` succesfully completes on your local machine and does the `rails s` starts?

Comment: from gemfile.lock: `RUBY VERSION  ruby 2.4.1p111. PLATFORMS ruby`. `bundle install` works fine, and `rails s` as well. The app works fine locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default interpreter is currently Ruby 2.3.3. You can specify a different Ruby version by writing the version name to a `.ruby-version` file in your application directory. For example:

```
2.2.5
```

When a `.ruby-version` file is present, the runtime attempts to download and install the specified version of Ruby. If the version cannot be satisfied, you will receive an error message when deploying your application.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime

Comment: Thanks! I tried using the google cloud service help, but I should have known better.